# Why is the displayed name in bash different from the one in /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, bash, vps, passwd

I remotely SSH login as root (using PUTTY),

The bash shell prompt becomes:

```
[root@yukiko /]#
```

When I entered:

```
getent passwd
```

The first line I see is this one:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Shouldn't the bash shell prompt look like this? (which corresponds to the first line in /etc/passwd) ?

```
[root /]#
```

This is a VPS server with CentOS installed, yukiko is the desired customer login id I provided to the hosting company.

Comment: In this case yukiko is the machine's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type:

```
echo $PS1
```

at the Bash prompt, you'll see:

```
[\u@\h \w]
```

That says to display the username, an at sign, the hostname and the current working directory all inside square brackets.

Evidently, they've given your server the same hostname as your customer login ID.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I get this: [\u@\h \W]\$